# A sensor which can measure the vibration of a material

Tags: sensor, fft, vibration, piezoelectricity, music

I am planning on making a musical instrument where I require the conversion of vibration of a material to voltage. The idea is to make a percussion instrument where I hit a plate made of a certain type of material. Based on the different areas on which I hit the plate, the vibrations will be different and after converting the vibrations to voltage, I will take the FFT of the signals to differentiate the different areas on which I hit the material and map it to produce a particular sound. I know that piezoelectric sensor is a material which converts pressure to voltage but I am not sure if it will be robust enough. Is there any alternative I can use?

Comment: So if it makes a noise then a microphone...

Comment: Accelerometry and strain gauges come to mind.

Comment: @SolarMike  I haven't chosen a material yet but it must not make too much noise or otherwise it will interfere with the sound of the musical instrument.

Comment: Use the microphone to measure the noise the plate makes - any other sensor except optical will cause a change ... but what about a laser? Measure the change of position...

Comment: Magnetic sensors are a possibility as are piezoelectric. As well as the various technologies of microphones (condenser, electret, MEMS digital microphones, to mention a few). Have you done research into how other musical instruments pick up vibrations? Electric guitar pickups generally use magnetic pickups, acoustic can use a mix of piezo and microphone because they want to pick up the strings and the wood.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer to this. In fact, many electronic musical instruments have been designed in the past, using a variety of sensors, and the tone and response depends on the material used, sensor, position of sensor and so on. It's basically trial and error and decide what you like. Some possible sensors:

- piezo
- accelerometer
- microphone
- strain gauge
- magnet and hall effect sensor
- pickup coil
- laser

and there may be others too.

Answer (score 0):

What you plan seems very difficult to achieve. You are talking about different vibrations when you hit different places. What do you think will be different? Sound loudness level or sound frequency? If you go with frequency, then a microphone would be your device. Measuring sound loudness differences in a hard material is very hard to achieve, because it is a very tiny difference.

Comment: I plan to do both. My concern is mostly with the frequency. For the loudness, I will take the rms value of the input signal to the microcontroller and normalise it. Then I will multiply the normalised value with the audio samples which have to be played.

Comment: Ok, so you need a Microphone and you need to measure the frequency and amplitude of the Mic. voltage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would like to correlate position of impact on the striking surface to frequency.  The mic followed by appropriate signal processing will produce the time, frequency, and amplitude.  A second sensor system is needed to determine point of impact.

As you mentioned, piezo might work, but I suspect this would require an array of sensors rather than a single sensor.  Another thought might be to surround your striking surface with an array based on optical touch sensor technology such as [this](http://baanto.com/optical-touch-screen-technology) and shown in the illustration below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the striking surface is semi-rigid, then you may consider using a MEMS accelerometer.

An accelerometer could directly measure the vibration of the material.

- I would suggest one with either an analog or SPI output.  One with an I2C output will be too slow.
- You need one that can measure large amounts of acceleration (like ±20G not ±2G).
- You need one with wide bandwidth (probably a few kHz min).  But that depends on the vibrational frequency of your striking surface.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems very similar to the automatic scoring systems in use in some outdoor shooting ranges. I mean the ranges with assault rifles and metallic targets, not paper.

Apparently, at least two technologies are used. One using 4 microphones. Another using lasers.

For inspirations, I suggest to have a look at the patent which is now expired: USRE32123E

Google Patent Search is your friend to find it using its number.

Comment: Arg..... I just saw that the question is several years old....

Answer (score 0):

You know the oscillating modes of the plate - easy to model for the actual material and shape using FEM or look up in tables. The plate has to be suspended so that the modes are not affected too much.

Then, place several accelerometers on the plate, to detect which vibrational mode it's in, and in which of the antinodes the strike occurred.